# E: unable to find the package lx_lsqman

Tags: 12.04, installation

I was trying to install lx_lsqman (bioinfo software) wen  got the error I have updated and upgraded and then tried to install the software still I get the error:

```
E: unable to locate package.
```

Answer (score 1):

Lsqman isn't in the Ubuntu repositories [and never has been](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lsqman).

They do offer [downloads and rough instructions](http://xray.bmc.uu.se/markh/usf/) on how to get and install it. I'd follow those.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I am new to ubuntu. i have downloaded the linux-64-binaries and distribution kit from the link which you have suggested. how to install lsqman?